# MongoDb - Update collection atomically if set does not exist

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following document in my collection:

```
{
   "_id":NumberLong(106379),
   "_class":"x.y.z.SomeObject",
   "name":"Some Name",
   "information":{
      "hotelId":NumberLong(106379),
      "names":[
         {
            "localeStr":"en_US",
            "name":"some Other Name"
         }
      ],
      "address":{
         "address1":"5405 Google Avenue",
         "city":"Mountain View",
         "cityIdInCitiesCodes":"123456",
         "stateId":"CA",
         "countryId":"US",
         "zipCode":"12345"
      },
      "descriptions":[
         {
            "localeStr":"en_US",
            "description": "Some Description"
         }
      ],
   },
   "providers":[

   ],
   "some other set":{
      "a":"bla bla bla",
      "b":"bla,bla bla",
   }
   "another Property":"fdfdfdfdfdf"
}
```

I need to run through all documents in collection and if `"providers": []` is empty I need to create new set based on values of information section.

I'm far from being MongoDB expert, so I have the few questions:

- Can I do it as atomic operation?
- Can I do this using MongoDB console? as far as I understood I can do it using `$addToSet` and `$each` command?
- If not is there any Java based driver that can provide such functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I do it as atomic operation?

Every document will be updated in an atomic fashion. There is no "atomic" in MongoDB in the sense of RDBMS, meaning all operations will succeed or fail, but you can prevent other writes interleaves using [$isolated operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/isolated/)

> Can I do this using MongoDB console?

Sure you can. To find all empty providers array you can issue a command like:

`db.zz.find(providers :{ $size : 0}})`

To update all documents where the array is of zero length with a fixed set of string, you can issue a query such as

`db.zz.update({providers : { $size : 0}}, {$addToSet : {providers : "zz"}})`

If you want to add a portion to you document based on a document's data, you can use the notorious [$where query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), **do mind the warnings appearing in that link**, or - as you had mentioned - query for empty provider array, and use [cursor.forEach()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)

> If not is there any Java based driver that can provide such functionality?

Sure, you have a Java driver, as for each other major programming language. It can practically do everything described, and basically every thing you can do from the shell. Is suggest you to get started from [the Java Language Center](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/).

Also there are several frameworks which facilitate working with MongoDB and bridge the object-document world. I will not give a least here as I'm pretty biased, but I'm sure a quick Google search can do.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I'm missing some point. if I'm doing it using mongo driver or even Spring data, I would first get an entity as pojo, update appropriate document sections and save document. Is this set of operation atomic?

Comment: If you do it using Java MongoDB driver or Spring the update operation will be atomic. Note however that you can encounter a lost update. "your" connection issues a find query, manipulate the BSON as Java object. Meanwhile some other connection can update the document your object represents. So once you issue an update. The previous updated data will be lost.

Comment: So, is there any way, to prevent it?

Comment: No MongoDB doesn't try to prevent non-repeatable-reads & lost updates, which you can achieve in RDBMS using repeatable read isolation level. For a single document however you can atomically first change, and then return a document (old or new version) using [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/)

Answer (score 1):

```
db.so.find({ providers: { $size: 0} }).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.providers.push( doc.information.hotelId );
    db.so.save(doc);
});
```

This will push the `information.hotelId` of the corresponding document into an empty `providers` array. Replace that with whatever field you would rather insert into the `providers` array.

Comment: That is not atomic and thus doesn't answer the question.